# ERP What to read/practice?

Tags: axapta, erp, sap-erp

I had been learning ERP applications this summer during internship. As I am a programmer about to graduate, I want to have a solid software branch that would get me through till I am sure about what to do next (till I have a nice view of the big picture). Till now, I have just learned what I was asked. That's not a good way to specialize you know. I don't think I should do that after graduation.

Anyway I had spent internship very productive I think. Also ERP looks like a nice job. I would even say it seems easy. Not much hardcore programming at least. Pardon me if I am wrong, I am just a beginner you know ;) . So I have learned Axapta there(the old version yeah). The people there supplied me with some resource too. I know overview of ERP systems but I haven't coded anything yet.

To get to the point. Hopefully I will have a MSDNAA account soon then I can download Dynamic AX SDK and practice. Although I hear that SAP ERP is much more common here in my country. I know NOTHING about SAP. How much difference is there between two? If Axapta knowledge wouldn't help me in SAP I won't spend much time with it. How can I learn SAP ERP at home? Don't get me wrong I'm not a fanboy for either of them. I am just trying to get knowledgeable with the whole thing.

Share anything you think that might help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recomend the AX book "Inside Dynamics AX" published by MS Press. There is a PDF version that you can get on some places in internet of the 4.0 version. The 2009 version is only on paper. It is a very good book to learn an practice in AX development.

Also you have lots of usefull info for free in MSDN:

About the product:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/ax/default.aspx

About the SDK:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd448627.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Since i don't know much of Axapta, i will only adress the SAP part.

> How can I learn SAP at home ?

You can download a basic SAP system from [SDN](http://sdn.sap.com) (Sap Developper Network). This will help you on the technical side to learn the proprietary langage.  This site can also be used to find informations, how-to and so on.

In sap's world, people are separated into "functionnal" and "technical". The first kind possess the knowdledge to convert the customer requests into the ERP customizing. the later can modify the code to add new functionnalities.

However, ERP can be seen has a executable model of the enterprise, and thus possess a lot of different sides (Human resources, Finance, Logistics... and so on).  Depedending on what you want to do, you **will** have to learn a specific domain, since the quantity of information is so vast.

Hopes this helps
Guillaume